# Spark Weighted Least Squares for Exponential fitting

Tags: apache-spark, least-squares, exponential

Is this possible to use Spark [WLS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala) module for semivariogram exponential fitting of this form:

*γ(h) = c<sub>0</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> (1 - e <sup>-h/c<sub>2</sub></sup>)*